# Existence of infinite sequence of nonsingular matrices whose sums are degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does there exist an infinite sequence $A_1$, ..., $A_n$, ... of nonsingular matrices $n \times n$ over R such that the sum $A_i+A_j$ is degenerate for all distinct $i$ and $j$?